# SmartGit not working on RPi400: cannot execute binary file

Tags: raspberry-pi, smartgit

Good day

I am trying to install smartgit on a RPi400 fresh install.

What I have tried:

1. I navigate to the directory that contains the smartgit.sh and run `./smartgit.sh` Terminal returns:

```
>>If you experience strange GUI bugs or crashes, try setting GTK_THEME=Adwaita.
./smartgit.sh: line 150: /home/.../Programs/smartgit/jre/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

2. I have also tried installing Java (java install [link](https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-raspberry-pi/))
3. I have also uncommented `GTK_THEME=Adwaita` within the smartgit.sh file.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted SmartGit and was told that SmartGit is not supported on on Raspberry Os at all. :(